# SQL how to determine hours from date per day and workstation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a query which gives me output

```
select distinct(d.data_name) ,h.workstation_name, h.type_id, convert(varchar(19),(h.insert_date),120) as start
from data d, process_data_history h 
where h.data_id = d.data_id
and h.type_id between '500' and '5001'
and h.workstation_name like 'PL1W7D-105120'
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), h.insert_date, 126) LIKE '2016-04%'
order by d.data_name, start ;
```

And output looks like this

```
data_name                     workstation_name  type_id        start
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   500     2016-04-05 12:45:38
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   501     2016-04-05 12:45:38
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   600     2016-04-05 12:45:39
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   601     2016-04-05 12:45:39
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   4001    2016-04-05 14:06:04
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   4000    2016-04-05 14:05:55
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   4100    2016-04-05 14:06:05
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   4101    2016-04-05 14:10:43
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   5000    2016-04-05 14:10:43
WE228JP_2016_04_05__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   5001    2016-04-05 14:10:45
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   500     2016-04-06 14:10:46
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   600     2016-04-06 14:10:47
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   501     2016-04-06 14:10:47
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   601     2016-04-06 14:10:48
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   4000    2016-04-06 15:30:07
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   4001    2016-04-06 15:30:18
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   4100    2016-04-06 15:30:18
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   4101    2016-04-06 15:35:01
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   5000    2016-04-06 15:35:01
WE228JP_2016_04_06__10_33_03    PL1W7D-105120   5001    2016-04-06 15:35:03
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105122   500     2016-04-05 12:45:38
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105122   501     2016-04-05 12:45:38
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105122   600     2016-04-05 12:45:39
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105120   601     2016-04-05 12:45:39
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105122   4001    2016-04-05 14:06:04
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105122   5000    2016-04-05 14:10:43
WE228JP_2016_04_15__10_03_03    PL1W7D-105122   5001    2016-04-05 14:10:45
```

Also i know that

ID 500 600 ...5000 represents start time of steps (programs)

ID 501 601 ...5001  represents end time of steps (programs)

So i need to know for how long workstation was working per day:

So desired output would be like this (it's example):

```
data_name                     workstation_name        Hours
2016-04-05                    PL1W7D-105120     22 hours
2016-04-06                    PL1W7D-105120     21 hours
2016-04-15                    PL1W7D-105122     17 hours
```

Any hint how i could do that? Anything will do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
select d.data_name, h.workstation_name, h.type_id,
       datediff(hour, min(insert_date), max(insert_date)) as hours_sortof
from data d join
     process_data_history h 
     on h.data_id = d.data_id
where h.type_id between '500' and '5001' and 
      h.workstation_name like 'PL1W7D-105120'
      h.insert_date >= '2016-04-01' and h.insert_date < '2016-05-01'
group by d.date_name, h.workstation_name,
order by d.data_name, start ;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Do not convert dates to strings for comparison purposes.  SQL Server has very nice date/time functionality built into the system.
- Only use `LIKE` on string constants.  Implicit conversion can be a major source of problems.
- The `hours_sortof` is based on how SQL Server handles the differences of times. It counts hour boundaries rather than actual hours.  For more refinement, use a smaller increment, such as minutes or seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your output data into a table (or temporary table) then this should work. Your data has an event which starts before it ends!

```
;with  x as
(
    select  data_name, workstation_name, event_id = type_id/10, endEventIndicator = type_id%10, timestamp = start
from Data
)
select Date = cast(starts.timestamp as date), starts.workstation_name, sum(DateDiff(hour, starts.timestamp, ends.timestamp))
from x starts inner join x as ends
on starts.event_id =  ends.event_id
and starts.endEventIndicator = 0 and ends.endEventIndicator = 1
and starts.workstation_name = ends.workstation_name
group by cast(starts.timestamp as date), starts.workstation_name
```

Comment: I wil try to test it, but i am not sure i am capable to do that yet :) Will see.